# How to match only first occurence before some arbitrary character using regex in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have an example:
`s = "condition 10c of application 152301 ( materials ), condition 11 ( plans ), 2019."`

And regex which should matches **every first** number (or it's slight variant) before **each** round bracket which appears in sentence.

Simply this works for normal cases but I've found it matches more than one numbers within each group:

```
reg = "\d+\w{0,1}(?=\s*.*?\()"
re.findall(reg, s, flags=re.I)
```

How to get only `10c` and `11` and skip `152301` with pure regex?

**EDIT**

I guess I've found i accidently, just change one character within the regex (plus adding a group):

```
reg = "(\d+\w{0,1})(?:\s*.*?\()"
```

Not 100% it's correct for my every case.

Comment: So what is the final output you want?

Comment: just `['10c', '11']`

Comment: you can try [this](https://regex101.com/r/qAQ6YV/1/)